# WatchKit deployment target iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I am using Xcode 7.0.1 and trying to build and app for iOS 9.0 and watchOS 2 and keep getting the below error when I build in Xcode

error: WatchKit apps must have a deployment target equal to iOS 8.2 (was 9.0).

I am using code which requires iOS 9.0 so I have gone into the project/targets Build settings and into IOS Deployment Target and set to 9.0 and get the above error.  Changing IOS Deployment Target to 8.2 does not work as then I get a different error as I am using code which requires iOS 9.0

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you change Deployment Target of both of WatchKit app and WatchApp?

Comment: Yes, I changed the Deployment Target for the app project, app target, watch kit extension, and watch kit app all to 9.0

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242067/watchkit-apps-must-have-a-deployment-target-equal-to-ios-8-2-was-8-3, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044941/is-the-deployment-target-must-be-8-2-when-i-develop-with-the-watchkit. The 2nd may be of help (setting the base SDK but not the target for your iOS app).

Comment: And perhaps most relevant: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2410/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40015545-CH1-VALIDATION_TROUBLESHOOTING-WATCHKIT_APPS_MUST_HAVE_A_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_EQUAL_TO_IOS_8_2